# Multiple Nested IndexEmbedded not updating index in hibernate search

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity configured (@Indexed) to use Hibernate search.  I have some properties configured (@Field) as well and I am able to query and get accurate results back.  The problem is when I try to update one of my @IndexEmbedded properties.  After I do an update, the index is not updated, so when I do a search, stale data is displayed.

Here is my config:

1st Entity

```
    @Indexed
    public class Strain extends BaseEntity {

        @IndexedEmbedded
        @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="strain")
        private Set<TestResult> testResults = new HashSet<TestResult>();
```

2nd Entity

```
    @Entity
    public class TestResult extends BaseEntity {

       @ContainedIn
       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
       private Strain strain;

       @IndexedEmbedded
       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
       private TestType testType;
```

3rd Entity

```
    @Entity
    public class TestType extends BaseEntity {

        @IndexedEmbedded
        @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Test test;

        @ContainedIn
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="testType")
        private Set<TestResult> testResults = new HashSet<TestResult>();
```

4th Entity

```
    @Entity
    public class Test extends BaseEntity {

        @ContainedIn
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="test")
        private Set<TestType> testTypes = new HashSet<TestType>();
```

When I make updates to a Test or TestType, the index is not updated.  Using Luke, I can see that the index for the Strain ID is associated to a TestResult, TestType and a Test. So, not sure where else I should look.

After more research, it seems like after the initial search query, subsequent queries are not retrieving data from the database and just returning results from the initial query.  The first query works fine, but subsequent queries look like they are cached.

thanks